# Variável global ou banco de dados sempre

Tags: javascript, html, banco-de-dados

Eu fiz um aplicativo utilizando a biblioteca jQuery Mobile, é um aplicativo para dividir conta.

Eu criei um objeto principal chamado `conta` e ele é incrementado de acordo com as ações do usuário (código abaixo). Como as páginas estão todas em um arquivo HTML, eu utilizei somente um arquivo JS também e fiquei trabalhando com as variáveis globais para armazenar informação, já que não preciso dar load no arquivo para trocar de página. No final, na hora de salvar, eu uso o JSON e passo todo o objeto `conta` para o localStorage.

## Pergunta

Devo sempre ir armazenando e buscando os dados no banco ou posso utilizar as variáveis globais para armazenar dados em situações que a página não terá o load da página? Qual é a melhor prática?

Código:

```
/*********************************************************
Todo o codigo eh em funcao deste objeto, que esta sempre mudando
**************************************************************/
var conta = {

    idConta: 0,
    nomeConta: "",
    data: "",
    contaCarregada: false,

    pessoas: {
        pessoa: [], //nome + id
        quantAdd: 0,

    },

    produtos: {
        produto: [], //aqui vai id, nome, quant... de cada produto adicionado
        quantAdd: 0,
        totalInserido: 0
    },

    jaCalculado: false,
    produtoAlterado: false

};
```

Comment: Minha opinião: Vc pode usar um setTimeOut para de vez em quando ver se algo mudou e salvar no banco. Imagina que alguém fechou o aplicativo sem querer: Se tiver só na memória vai perder as informações, se tiver persistido vai poder voltar da onde parou.

Comment: Eu uso global. Usando settimeout é interessante. Mais não use salvar sem ele por que sempre que alguém mudar alguma coisa dependendo do aparelho pode dar uma travadinha. Kk